# Is there any way to figure out the website whether it's made by using spring framework or not?

Tags: spring, frameworks

I know that there are some sites which can figure out which tools have developers used when they build the web site.

For example, I can figure out whether the site has been built with wordpress or not from this page www.isitwp.com

Is there any ways to figure out what kind of framework the web site is using? or figure out the web site which has been built by using spring framework?

How can I know?

Comment: You can try http://builtwith.com/

Comment: @Piotr Rudnicki Thank you!

Comment: @PiotrRudnicki I have another question. If the site is using J2EE framework then is this site got to do with spring framework? or is there any possibility that this site could be renewed with spring framework?

Comment: In general there's no way to know what back-end technology a page uses. The page linked above doesn't even try to make a guess regarding the back-end technology (try checking with http://spring.io). You can try deducing the answer yourself from things like URL naming conventions, paths, HTTP response headers. You could also try exploiting some known vulnerabilities.